Setting vscode behaviour of (not) selecting code when jumping code structure via outline
Is there some setting to disable the behaviour in vscode to select the whole code body of a function/method when navigating and jumping to the code via outline?
I don't want to copy or delete the code when I'm navigating it and so it is always one input more to unselect every time.

When I single click an item in the Outline view, it jumps there but doesn't select anything.  When I double-click an item in the Outline, it jumps AND selects that block.  Are you seeing something different on a single click?
